Error 500 internal server error while uploading an image .NET 7
Problem: when submitting a POST request to upload an image along with other form data in an ASP.NET Core Web API application, I get a 500 Internal Server error. Without providing an image, the request succeeds, but the image name remains null and no image is saved. The application aims to store the uploaded image in a specified directory within the web root.
Description: when attempting to upload an image along with other form data via a POST request in an ASP.NET Core Web API application, a http 500 Internal Server error is encountered. This error only occurs when an image is provided in the request; submitting the request without an image succeeds, but the image name remains null and no image is saved. The application is designed to store uploaded images in a specified directory within the web root.
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostAdmin(string _userRole, int _userId, [FromForm] PostAdminDto dto)
{
    var userRole = _userRole;
    var userId = _userId;

    if (userRole == null)
    {
        return NotFound("Session data not found.");
    }
    
    if (userRole != "Manager")
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden, "Access denied.");
    }
    
    try
    {
        var admin = new Admin
        {
            Name = dto.Name,
            Phone = dto.Phone,
            MgrID = userId,
            Email = dto.Email,
            Password = dto.Password,
            Address = dto.Address,
            Salary = dto.Salary,
            CompID = dto.CompID,
        };
    
        if (dto.Img != null)
        {
            var fileName = await UploadImage(dto.Img, admin.Id);
            admin.ImgName = fileName;
        }
    
        await _context.AddAsync(admin);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    
        return Ok(admin);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while processing the request: {ex}");
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "An error occurred while processing the request.");
    }
}

[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public async Task<string> UploadImage(IFormFile imageFile, int adminId)
{
    if (imageFile == null || imageFile.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Image file is required.");
    }

    var fileName = $"{adminId}_{DateTime.Now.Ticks}{Path.GetExtension(imageFile.FileName)}";
    var imagesDirectory = Path.Combine(_hosting.WebRootPath, "images"); // Corrected path
    var filePath = Path.Combine(imagesDirectory, fileName);
    
    using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await imageFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }
    
    return fileName;
}


when i  don't provide an image the code worked correctly and put in imgName "Null"
if i sent an image it gave this error

Use _hosting.ContentRootPath and ensure the directory "images" exists in your project
